# What is the DLL loading behavior when using DllImport[] in C#?

Tags: c#, dll, import, behavior

Using the following code as example:

```
    [DllImport("C:\\Users\\Rodrigo\\Desktop\\ds08_asio\\dsproEtherFaceAsio\\x64\\Debug\\dsproEtherFaceAsio.dll")]
    public static extern void open_console();

    [DllImport("C:\\Users\\Rodrigo\\Desktop\\ds08_asio\\dsproEtherFaceAsio\\x64\\Debug\\dsproEtherFaceAsio.dll")]
    public static extern int get_available_interface(int index, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] StringBuilder buffer, int maxSize);

    [DllImport("C:\\Users\\Rodrigo\\Desktop\\ds08_asio\\dsproEtherFaceAsio\\x64\\Debug\\dsproEtherFaceAsio.dll")]
    public static extern int get_buffer();

    [DllImport("C:\\Users\\Rodrigo\\Desktop\\ds08_asio\\dsproEtherFaceAsio\\x64\\Debug\\dsproEtherFaceAsio.dll")]
    public static extern int get_channels();
```

What would be the loading behaviour of the DLL? To be more specific, will each DllImport create one instance of the DLL and export a single function? Or will one instance of the DLL be created and all functions exported?

Comment: Just one, as you might expect.

Comment: Thats what I thought, but am having some strange behaviour of the dll. Thanks